# I am facing this error "Invalid escape sequence" in web driver

Tags: string, path

I am facing this error `"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"` while executing below line in web driver please help...

Line:

```
String path = ("<C:\\Users\my\workspace\deven01\test-output\emailable-report.html>";
```

Comment: Kindly format your question. And try to put '\\' everywhere you have used a single '\'.

Comment: No, do not put \\! Select text and click the `{}` button to format as code.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It looks like you did not escape every path separator in the path string.

Answer (score 2):

`\` begins an escape sequence. In the line `<C:\\Users\my\workspace\deven01\test-output\emailable-report.html>`, you attempt to use the escape sequences `\\`, `\m`, `\w`, `\d`, `\t`, and `\e`. The only valid ones are `\\`, which is equal to the character `\`, and `\t`, which is a tab character. The problem will be solved if you replace all but the first two `\`s with `\\`, like this:

```
"<C:\\Users\\my\\workspace\\deven01\\test-output\\emailable-report.html>"
```

For more reading, look at the second section of [this page about characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).